# Computing implied volatilities of ITM and OTM options

Tags: black-scholes, implied-volatility

For an ATM call the implied volatility can be computed by using the Newton-Raphson method:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.stats import norm

def bs_d1(S,K,T,sigma,R):
  return (np.log(S/K) + (r+sigma**2/2)*T)/(sigma*np.sqrt(T))

def bs_call(S,K,T,sigma,r):
  d1 = bs_d1(S,K,T,sigma,r)
  return S*norm.cdf(d1) - np.exp(-r*T)*K*norm.cdf(d1-sigma*np.sqrt(T))

def bs_vega(S,K,T,sigma,r):
  d1 = bs_d1(S,K,T,sigma,r)
  return S*np.sqrt(T)*norm.pdf(d1)

def sigma_i(c,S,K,T,r,eps=1e-3):

  # first approximation
  sigma = np.sqrt(2*np.pi/T)*c/S

  while True:
     diff = bs_call(S,K,T,sigma,r) - c
     vega = bs_vega(S,K,T,sigma,r)

     if np.abs(diff) < eps:
        break

     sigma = sigma - diff/vega


  return sigma
```

However the method fails when I use OTM and ITM calls since Vega becomes very close to zero. One example:

```
# OTM 

S = 100
K = 140
T = 0.25
r = 0.03
c = 0.0015581689540368482 # bs_call(S,K,T,0.2,r)

sigma = sigma_i(c,S,K,T,r)
```

Another example:

```
# ITM

S = 100
K = 80
T = 1.5
r = 0.03
c = 42.36652921873271 # bs_call(S,K,T,0.7,r)

sigma = sigma_i(c,S,K,T,r)
```

How to compute the implied volatility in these cases?

Comment: the problem you have, is that if the initially vol is too small, then the vega is tiny - i.e. nearly zero, which you then divide by. The best way of doing it i'm aware of is peter jaeckel's, you can see it [here](www.jaeckel.org), in a paper called "Let's Be Rational". I advise you read all of his papers, they're all interesting.

Comment: @will This fixes the problem in the example that I originally posted. Hovewer, it does not work with a new example.

Answer (score 2):

you can use this algoithm to calibrate volatility (the use of vega deos not work for far OTM and ITM options):

```
        define vol1=0.0;
        define vol2=1.99;
        define z;
        define z2;
        for (i=0;i<max_iterations;i++) {
            z=0.5*(vol1+vol2);
            z2=z/(1.0-z);
            if (price>bs_price(z2)) {
                vol1=z;
                vol2=vol2;
            } else {
                vol1=vol1;
                vol2=z;
            }
        }
        z=0.5*(vol1+vol2);
        return z/(1.0-z);
```

Comment: I see. One just uses the bisection method.

Comment: if you're going to do a bisection method, then if i recall, it's actually more efficient to use the golden ratio to get your next guess, rather than half way.